# In php when copying a file it doesn't show the content in the browser

Tags: php, file, copy

I have this code in the file register.php

```
copy("template.php", "username.php");
```

And then I have the file `welcome.php` which should make link to `username.php`. For any new registered user I should create a special page, like username1.php, username2.php, and all this links appear on welcome.php, so that every user should click on their own pages.

The file template.php works fine, it is executed in browser, but the new file shows a blank page in browser. What's the reason ? What should I do ?
If the file template.php would contain only html code, it would work fine, i tried it, but I need to put also php code in the file template.php, in which case the file username.php doesn't work, that's the problem.

The template.php contains

```
<?php
session_start(); // and also some decisions about session
?>

<html>
<body>
// some text
</body>
</html>
```

SOLVED

I have used

```
require("credentials.php");
```

and this file wasn't found (was only in the root), that's why the page stopped.

Comment: `copy()` doesn't output anything, it just copies the files on the server. What are you expecting to see in the browser?

Comment: PHP isn't executed in the browser, it's executed on the server.

Comment: Is `welcome.php` including `username.php` before or after the copy?

Comment: Show how you're using the file from `welcome.php`.

Comment: _“What should I do ?”_ - stop what you are doing :-) Why are you creating individual _files_ for each user to begin with? This is not the way this is generally handled. Instead, you should set up some sorting of _routing system_, that can get the username from the URL, and then _dynamically_ fetches/assembles the content to show for this individual user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cant comment yet.
I think you need to check the content of the template.php.

I tested the copy function and it worked.

here is the code i tested

ori.php

```
<?php
echo 'hi there';
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
copy('ori.php', 'copy.php');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, your example works for me too, but I use that "session" sequence and it doesn't work anymore, I don't know why!

Comment: It was my fault, sorry. I solved the bug. Thanks!